# Stay on screen for specific number of seconds, then go to next one?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, nstimer

I am trying to make a memory app, where the screen has to stay there for about 10 seconds, then it has to flip, or in other words, go to the next screen? Should I do this by using a timer and connecting it to the screen that I need to connect it to? I am a bit confused by how this works..

All help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes using NSTimer is the way to go. Try a timer with delay action. Since you already have the answer in your mind I did not put this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(selector) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
```

and have the selector load the new view.